# Best practice to log exceptions in Salesforce

Tags: debug-logs

Salesforce generated many log files and from there it is very difficult to find out our desired logs (exception logs ).

What is the best practice to do that?

Comment: Your own, custom logger.

Answer (score 1):

I would have following recommendations

1. Salesforce logging indeed is preety inconvenient however when you get used to it and understand how it works - usually you can dig into the root cause.
2. When developing apex code - you need to use `System.debug` statements. Make sure to assign proper `LoggingLevel` - then you can to leverage `DEBUG Level filters` granularly filter your logs.
3. You can build your own logger functionality (e.g. custom object with APEX logic) to log events that you want to monitor, there are plenty of patterns and examples online